# Displaying the base64 tiff images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display the base64 tif images in HTML. Below is my HTML code.

```
<img ng-if="fileExtension == 'tif'"  ng-src="data:image/tiff;base64,{{attachment}}" id="photo-id" style="width: 100%;padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px" />

<iframe ng-if="fileExtension == 'tif'" src="data:image/tiff;base64,{{attachment}}" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" >
            </iframe>
```

I tried above code but unable to display the tif images, can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which browser are you using??

Comment: I am using Chrome browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) link, Chrome doesn't support tiff image type. So you will have to convert it some other format(.jpg,.jpeg etc) and then show it in your html page.

Comment: Converted the tiff images to pdf file and it is working file. Thanks for informtion